# Cannot pass contents of html table as form data on a POST?

Tags: php, html, forms, html-table

I have a table, code as follow,
the table have select and checkbox, I try to wrap my table in a form and post to results.php to echo,
but when submit the form, it's not working. How to get the checkbox checked value from results.php?

```
<script>   
var currentSelected = "";
var currentItem = "";
function show(obj, item) {   
if (currentSelected != "" && currentSelected != obj) {
    currentSelected.checked = false;
    document.getElementById(currentItem).style.display = currentSelected.checked ? "block" : "none"; 

}
document.getElementById(item).style.display = obj.checked ? "block" :"none";
currentSelected = obj;
currentItem = item;
}
</script>
<form action="results.php" method="post">
    <table width="805" border="0" >
        <tr>
          <td width="30">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="30">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="30">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="30">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="38">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="25">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="114">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="456">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Range</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><p>
            <input type="checkbox" name="absolute" onChange="change(this)"  onclick="show(this,'s1');">
            Absolute</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>
            <input type="checkbox" name="quick" onChange="change(this)" onclick="show(this,'s2');">
            Quick</p></td>
        <td><p>
         <div id="s1" style="display:none">
            <input class="date" id="datepicker" type="text" value="" name="from"  placeholder="From" onFocus="this.value = '';" onBlur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = '';}" required=>
            <input class="date" id="datepicker1" type="text" value="" name="to" placeholder="To" onFocus="this.value = '';" onBlur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = '';}" required=>
            </div>
          </p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>
            <div id="s2" style="display:none">
            <select name="quickselect" id="quickselect"  >
                <option value="30">Last 30 minutes</option>
                <option value="60">Last 1 hour</option>
                <option value="4h">Last 4 hour</option>                 
              </select>
              </div>
          </p></td>
      </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Location</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td colspan="2">
       </td>
      </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>Index</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td colspan="2"><select name="loc" id="locselect" >
            <option value="la">LA</option>
            <option value="ny">NY</option>
            <option value="all">CA & NY </option>
          </select></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Keyword</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td colspan="2">
          <input type="text" name="keyword" id="keyword" width="200">
        </span></td>
      </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td colspan="3"><div class="bnr-btn">
          <input type="submit" value="Search">
          </div></td>
      </tr>
      </table>
      </form>
```

results.php

```
 <?php
   //how to echo the checkbox value ?????????

   $quickselect= $_POST["quickselect"];
   $locselect =$_POST["locselect "];
   $keyword = $_POST["keyword "];
  ?>
```

Comment: try something like `var_dump()`  or `print_r()` on $_POST var in result.php, and tell us what is been shown to you.  EG: `<?php var_dump($_POST); ?>`

Comment: when i press the submit ,it's didn't redirect to results.php

Comment: Delete all javascript and <script> tags from your file, check that you are not preventing default action of button nor form submit.

Comment: I have comment all javascript ,but still cannot redirect . the submit isn't work

Comment: Perhaps your code is not clean, tidy all your tags and keep only form elements, and try to send it again. Then, complete the table step by step. Its the only think i can tell you for the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To retreive a value from POST request using PHP you can use something like this

```
$checkbox = $_POST['absolute'];
```

The parameter name and the value is the same as on your html tag.

Eg:

`<input name="absolute" type="checkbox" value="Your value" />`

Comment: but if select the quick checkbox ? user will be select one checkbox

Comment: Although this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.

Comment: @matt.crawfoord you're missing the value attribute on your html? try adding that

Answer (score 0):

for checkbox :

```
$checkbox1=$_POST['absolute'];
$checkbox2=$_POST['quick'];
```

FOR get the date values

```
$from=$_POST['from'];
$to=$_POST['to'];
```

Comment: This is not a response to OP.